# Java add chars to a string

Tags: java, string, char

I have two strings in a java program, which I want to mix in a certain way to form two new strings. To do this I have to pick up some constituent chars from each string and add them to form the new strings. I have a code like this(this.eka and this.toka are the original strings):

```
String muutettu1 = new String();
String muutettu2 = new String();
muutettu1 += this.toka.charAt(0) + this.toka.charAt(1) + this.eka.substring(2);
muutettu2 += this.eka.charAt(0) + this.eka.charAt(1) + this.toka.substring(2);
System.out.println(muutettu1 + " " + muutettu2);
```

I'm getting numbers for the .charAt(x) parts, so how do I convert the chars to string?

Comment: Nice to see some Finnish code ;-)

Comment: As your example shows, you can also use `substring` to return a String directly. Any reason why you are using both `charAt` and `substring` in the same statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use always use `substring()` instead of `charAt()`

###### In this particular case, the values are mutable, consequently, we can use the built in **`String`** class  method *`substring()`* to solve this problem (***@see*** the example below):

###### *Example specific to the OP's use case:*

```
    muutettu1 += toka.substring(0,1) + toka.substring(1,2) + eka.substring(2);
   
    muutettu2 += eka.substring(0,1) + eka.substring(1,2) + toka.substring(2);
```

###### *Concept Example, (i.e Example showing the generalized approach to take when attempting to solve a problem using this concept)*

```
    muutettu1 += toka.substring(x,x+1) + toka.substring(y,y+1) + eka.substring(z);

    muutettu2 += eka.substring(x,x+1) + eka.substring(y,y+1) + toka.substring(z);
```

> ###### *"...Where x,y,z are the variables holding the positions from where to extract."*

Answer (score 15):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder
   .append(this.toka.charAt(0))
   .append(this.toka.charAt(1))
   .append(this.toka.charAt(2))
   .append(' ')  
   .append(this.eka.charAt(0))
   .append(this.eka.charAt(1))
   .append(this.eka.charAt(2));
System.out.println (builder.toString());
```

Comment: I think, your result will be wrong. subString(2) is the string beginning with the index 2.

Comment: Yep, I missed that.  Regardless, append is an overloaded method and you can pass it Strings as well.  The salient point here was to not use String directly and use StringBuilder (or StringBuffer if on older JRE) to minimize the performance cost.

Comment: a + b will be compiled to new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).toString() anyway.

Comment: I really like this answer, but why not an enhanced `for` loop? eg.  `for(String i : this.toka)` and do the same for `this.eka`

Comment: Try javap on both variants. (Haven't done it myself, but) likely the iterative form will peform superflous allocations for the 2 control structures (possibly unrolled by the compiler). Also do note that OP's Q did not indicate that the source Strings actually terminate at the indices provided, so it will need to be an explicit for loop form.

Answer (score 7):

The obvious conversion method is [Character.toString](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29).

A better solution is:

```
String muutettu1 = toka.substring(0,2) + eka.substring(2);
String muutettu2 = eka.substring(0,2) + toka.substring(2);
```

You should create a method for this operation as it is redundant.

The string object instatiantiation `new String()` is unnecessary. When you append something to an empty string the result will be the appended content.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert an integer into a String representation in two ways: 1) String.valueOf(a) with a denoting an integer 2) Integer.toString(a)

Answer (score -2):

This thing can adding a chars to the end of a string

```
StringBuilder strBind = new StringBuilder("Abcd");
strBind.append('E');
System.out.println("string = " + str);
//Output => AbcdE
str.append('f');
//Output => AbcdEf
```

Comment: What is this? Where does `str` come from? What are you even doing?

Comment: What is this? you didn't even declare what `str` was yet!

Comment: You answered this question with JavaScript lol. This is a question that references JAVA, a totally different language.