# How can i add a Char variable in a string variable

Tags: java, string, char

I want to make a code wich reads from the keyboard a character and that character i want to add it to a string variable

Example

```
char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
String l = "";
```

[my character from keyboard beeing now in "c" and "l" beeing empty]

How can i make "l" to add to it's value the character from "c"

I want to make that "l" to stock all the char introduced so it needs to concatenate "l" with "c"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java add chars to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654546/java-add-chars-to-a-string)

Comment: It's not the same thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
String l = "";
char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
l = l + String.valueOf(c);
```

Or,

```
StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
sBuilder.append(String.valueOf(c));
String l = sBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object, to which you can append `char` characters, then you convert it to a `String` with `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **[`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)**. It has a **[`append(char c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%29)** method to do exactly what you want.

Also, at the end of processing you can use its **[`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29)** method to get the equivalent `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
 String l = "";
 l=l+c;
 System.out.println(l);
```