# Plus operator - How to enforce String concatenation?

Tags: java, quine

While writing a Quine (i.e. a self-replicating program) in Java, I tried to indent output lines using tab characters:

```
...
char tab = '\t';
char qm = 34;
char comma = ',';
...
System.out.println(tab + tab + tab + qm + listing[i] + qm + comma);
...
```

This doesn't work because the plus operator in "tab + tab + ..." adds the tab character values rather than generating a string (61 = 9 + 9 + 9 + 34):

```
...
61    public static void main(String[] args) {",
...
```

Placing an empty string at the beginning does the job:

```
...
System.out.println("" + tab + tab + tab + qm + listing[i] + qm + comma);
...
```

However, I can't use plain quotation marks in the Quine setting as I need to escape them to output the program text itself.

I wonder if it is possible to enforce the interpretation of the plus operator as String concatenation WITHOUT explicitely using quotation marks or additional Java classes?

Answer (score 3):

Do you absolutely need to use +-signs? This'll do the trick too, and is designed for it in terms of performance:

```
String outputString = new StringBuilder()
    .append(tab).append(tab).append(tab).append(qm)
    .append(listing[i]).append(qm).append(comma)
    .toString();
System.out.println(outputString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.printf` instead of `System.out.println`

```
 char tab = '\t';
 char qm = 34;
 char comma = ',';
 System.out.printf("%c%c%c", tab, tab,comma);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder` to concatenate `char`s to `String`.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1654578/1651233) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can replace empty quotation marks with simple String constructor:

```
...
System.out.println(new String() + tab + tab + tab + qm + listing[i] + qm + comma);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance pointy of view [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) appending is better than [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) concatenation, but [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) doesn't provide thread safety.
If you need thread safety use [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).