# How to fix the recursive code error in CodingBat?

Tags: java, recursion, runtime-error, testcase

So, I was solving this problem on CodingBat

> Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) a new string where all
> appearances of "pi" have been replaced by "3.14".
>
> changePi("xpix") → "x3.14x"
>
> changePi("pipi") → "3.143.14"
>
> changePi("pip") → "3.14p"

Here is my code:

```
public String changePi(String str) {
    if (str.length() < 2)
        return str;
    char c1 = str.charAt(0);
    char c2 = str.charAt(1);
    if (c1 == 'p' && c2 == 'i')
        return "3.14" + changePi(str.substring(2));
    return c1 + c2 + changePi(str.substring(2));
}
```

This code is not working for many test cases as shown in the image below
[image]

I'm unable to understand what is wrong with my recursive code and why it is showing such output. Can anyone please help me in understanding what I did wrong?

Comment: Hint: In java, `'a' + 'b' + "c"` is not `"abc"`. Order of operations is what is killing your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java add chars to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654546/java-add-chars-to-a-string)

Comment: You can also check [Why is my char printing as a number instead of a character?](//stackoverflow.com/q/30763489) and [Java += operator on String with charAt() methods results in char addition](//stackoverflow.com/a/24938675)

Comment: The underlying issue is not because of string concatenation. I posted a fix below along with an explanation and correct output.

Comment: @kaan It may not have been the main issue, but it was causing the outputs to look *extra* wonky, and your fix did secretly handle it.

Comment: @DG4 Your solution is checking these indexes: `{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, ...` But you really want to check these ones: `{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple alternatives to the problem.  The second one is similar to your approach.  In the first one, I had originally included a target substitution text so I would need to determine its length.  Hence the `"pi".length()` use as I decided to leave it in.

```java
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] tests = {
                "piabcpiefgpi", "xxxxxxpix", "xpix", "pip", "3.14", "3.14p",
                "hip", "p", "x", "", "pixx", "xyzzy"
          };
          for (String t : tests) {
             System.out.println(t + " --> " + replaceV2(t));
          }
       }

       public static String replaceV1(String a) {
          int i = a.indexOf("pi");
          if (i < 0) {
             return a;
          }
          return replaceV1(
                a.substring(0, i) + "3.14" + a.substring(i + "pi".length()));
       }

       public static String replaceV2(String a) {
          if (a.length() < 2) {
             return a;
          }

          if (a.startsWith("pi")) {
             a = "3.14" + replaceV2(a.substring(2));
          }
          return a.substring(0, 1) + replaceV2(a.substring(1));
       }
    }
```

They both print the following.

```
piabcpiefgpi --> 3.14abc3.14efg3.14
xxxxxxpix --> xxxxxx3.14x
xpix --> x3.14x
pip --> 3.14p
3.14 --> 3.14
3.14p --> 3.14p
hip --> hip
p --> p
x --> x
 --> 
pixx --> 3.14xx
xyzzy --> xyzzy
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution needs a small tweak – when you've found a `p` and `i` together, you are correctly skipping ahead 2 characters to look at the remainder of the string – you're doing that with `return "3.14" + changePi(str.substring(2));`.

However, when you do *not* find a `p` and `i` together, you need to change your logic to skip ahead just one character instead of two. So instead of this:

```
return c1 + c2+ changePi(str.substring(2));
```

do this:

```
return c1 + changePi(str.substring(1));
```

After making that change, I get the following output (using each of your inputs) which matches your expected outputs:

```
x3.14x
3.143.14
3.14p
3.14
hip
p
x

3.14xx
xyzzy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''  change pi to 3.14 python code'''

def changePi(s):
    if len(s) == 2 and s == 'pi' :  return '3.14'
    if len(s) <= 2 :  return s 
    chars , sub = s[0:2] , s[1:]
    if chars == 'pi':
       chars = '3.14'
       sub = sub[1:]
    else:  chars =  chars[0]
    return chars + changePi(sub) 

print changePi("xpix") 
print changePi("pipi") 
print changePi("pip")
```